# Formly, primeng not able to set value of mindate(datepicker) in component using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am using angular formly and primeng. I have FormlyFieldCalendar and AppComponent in place.
Setting the property of minDate in  and initialiting the value in FormlyFieldCalendar with minDate works fine, but when i am trying to set the minDate in AppComponent field its not working.
Please find below both the scenarios, i have built the sample on StackBlitz for demonstration with link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-primeng-d7v5g4-nu6ctj?file=app/formly-field-primeng-calendar.ts

**Scenario 1:** (Works fine)

[image]

**Scenario 2:** (Not working)

I now tried removing the code of setting minDate in FormlyFieldCalendar instead trying to set in Appcomponent by 2 ways.

1. By assigning in templateOptions.
2. By using datePickerOptions provided in formly.dev webpage but seems doesnt work with primeng.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While assiging minDate in FormlyFieldCalendar Component we need to make sure we use alias to. It is an alias for field.templateOptions

- -[minDate] ="minDate"

- +[minDate] ="to.minDate"